# console.log error showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get into javascript and just figure out how how to print statements in the console.
I keep getting this error in the google chrome console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

my code is

```
<html>

<script>
    console.log(“Hello world!”);
</script>

</html>
```

I'm sure its something really simple that I'm missing.
I wrote the code on the textedit app on mac and then converted it to an html file.

Comment: Pay attention to what you copy paste. The quotes surrounding `Hello world!` is the problem. Manually type it and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using “ and ”, which are not valid quotes in the Javascript language. You should use ' or " instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`console.log(“Hello world!”);`

to

`console.log("Hello world!");`

`“` is not valid. Downside to copy/paste :)